# Really Slow boot

Tags: boot, services

This is the output of the command `systemd-analyze blame`:

How many of these can I disable?

```
38.257s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
31.175s snapd.service                                        
29.485s mysql.service                                        
22.252s systemd-journal-flush.service                        
16.657s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
14.747s udisks2.service                                      
12.817s dev-sda2.device                                      
11.724s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
8.506s accounts-daemon.service                              
7.890s ModemManager.service                                 
7.342s dev-loop6.device                                     
7.197s dev-loop19.device                                    
7.190s dev-loop10.device                                    
6.637s dev-loop11.device                                    
6.501s dev-loop8.device                                     
6.484s polkit.service                                       
6.464s dev-loop4.device                                     
6.428s NetworkManager.service                               
6.399s dev-loop15.device                                    
6.316s dev-loop17.device                                    
6.272s dev-loop9.device                                     
6.209s dev-loop7.device                                     
6.173s dev-loop14.device
```

Comment: please add more information about your system,cpu,memory,dual boot/single boot,what flavour are you running?

Comment: Add the output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` as well.